# Transform functions to a different space

Tags: functions, transformation

Let's say I have a function $$f(x)=\frac{a}{x_0}(x-x_0)^2$$
I can plot this function on a XY plane by taking, $y=f(x)$. It's a parabola centered at $x_0$ and stretched by $a$ along the y-axis. My question is, how would I plot this function in a $x$ vs $y^2$ plane.

I don't want a solution to that problem, I want you to point me in the right direction. I want to solve it myself. I am clueless where to begin. Or in general, how do I transform a function in $x$ vs $y$ plane to say $x$ vs $k(y)$ plane.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is plot the function given by $k(f(x))$. This is called a composite function, denoted $k \circ f$.

For example, if $f(x) = x$, and I want to plot this on the $x,y$-plane, then I get  a diagonal going through the origin with a slope of 1. If I want to plot this on the $x,y^2$-plane, I first let $k(y) = y^2$, then I get the composite function given by $k(f(x)) = (x)^2 = x^2$, and so the plot in $x,y^2$-plane of $f(x) = x$ is just a parabola.

Comment: Let's say, I have a function $y=x^2$. If I plot it in XY plane, I get a parabola. Now, if $k(x)=x^2$, then $y=k$. If I plot the function in X-K plane, I get a straight line, i.e. to say that $y=x^2$ is a straight line in $x$ vs $k(x)$ plane. But according to you, if the new function is $f' = k\circ f = k(x^2) = (x^2)^2 = x^4$, but it should be $f'(x)=x$

Comment: Why would it be a straight line in $x,k$-space? It is $y$ that is equal to $k$, but $x$ is not equal to $k$. $k$ is $x^2$. Therefore, in $x,k$-space, you still get a parabola. You only get a straight line in $y,k$-space.

Comment: And it is in $x,y^2$-space that you get the $x^4$-curve. But you haven't introduced anything corresponding to $y^2$ so that's why you don't get that curve.